# No module named rest_auth

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

Getting the error:
"ImportError: No module named rest_auth"

Full trace: https://dpaste.de/UHyx

When I try to run the server using 'python2.7 manage.py runserver'

My partner is working off the same venv as me but is able to run the server successfully when he runs 'python2.7 manage.py runserver'. We both have identical(we believe) venv installs and packages.

Not quite sure what can be done to fix this error as I cant really get much from the trace,but I believe it could be something wrong with my python version..

Comment: Show settings.py INSTALLED_APPS section

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup https://dpaste.de/Vyhq

Comment: Ok. And show pip freeze

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup pip freeze resulted in https://dpaste.de/ULVs

Comment: how about : `pip install django-rest-auth` ?

Comment: @Loïc output from running ur mentioned command https://dpaste.de/gqn8 tried it with sudo too..

Comment: Are you using MacOS ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to install django-rest-auth :

```
pip install django-rest-auth
```

You may encounter some problems on MacOS which it seems you can fix following this :

- [Unable to install nltk on Mac OS El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898583/unable-to-install-nltk-on-mac-os-el-capitan/33024464#33024464)

Or this :

- ["OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted" when installing Scrapy in OSX 10.11 (El Capitan) (System Integrity Protection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900008/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-when-installing-scrapy-in-osx-10-11)

Second one seems not to be very system friendly, try first, first.

Comment: Had to leave station for a while, will test this solution shortly

Comment: 'pip install --user django-rest-auth' solved the problem, on the El capitan system

Answer (score 0):

I had it installed in my virtual env. But for reasons unknown to me I still have to install it globally for the app to be used in venv.

linux_machine:/#**pip install django-rest-auth**

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it...

First run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

fix any errors that pop up... for me some modules weren't installed globally so for that I used pip instead of pipenv

Then

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Then lastly

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).