# Cannot install scrapy on El Capitan

Tags: python, pip, osx-elcapitan

I have the same problem as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900008/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-when-installing-scrapy-in-osx-10-11?rq=1).
I am trying to install `scrappy` with `pip` but scrappy seems to be dependent on a version of `six` different from the system's version and SIP wouldn't allow the `six` to be change. I tried install python with `brew` and `--ignored-installed six`. Neither worked.

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-djuFg2-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Find the full error hear: https://gist.github.com/harinsa/950ad7fb4100fcd8c89c

The only solution I didn't try yet is disabling SIP in recovery mode, but it was advised against. **Is there any other method I could try before resorting to disabling SIP?**

Comment: are u in the latest xcode version?

Comment: also, what do you get after ´pip install --upgrade six´?

Comment: @GermanRosales update with the full error, xcode version 7.1.1

Comment: So do you have other installation of python, different from the system one, am i correct? will that one let you install Scrapy in a virtualenv ?