# Problems installing the latest version of the EB CL

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, osx-elcapitan

```
sudo pip install awsebcli
```

> Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in
>   main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317,
>   in run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 725, in
>   install
>       requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 752,
>   in uninstall
>       paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line
>   115, in remove
>   .....

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900008/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-when-installing-scrapy-in-osx-10-11

Comment: Thanks @Forge !  --ignore-installed did the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo pip install --ignore-installed awsebcli
```