# Issue when trying to install ipython through terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal, ipython

I want to install `ipython` through the macOS terminal (I have tried both `easy_install` and `pip`), but a specific problem always occurs, which is described in the last line:

```
Searching for ipython
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/ipython/
Best match: ipython 5.1.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/d4/0b/70c913ed4c99eb84c589e5e25b28985ba93ca2a57e08959bb14372f7f5f8/ipython-5.1.0.zip#md5=9d6a0bd4d4c18a4dc88d2f69dfefdea7
Processing ipython-5.1.0.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-f_u6YT/ipython-5.1.0/setup.cfg
Running ipython-5.1.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-f_u6YT/ipython-5.1.0/egg-dist-tmp-3mwkoQ
checking package data
check version number
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-5.1.0-py2.7.egg
Extracting ipython-5.1.0-py2.7.egg to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Adding ipython 5.1.0 to easy-install.pth file
Installing ipython script to /usr/local/bin
Installing iptest2 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing iptest script to /usr/local/bin
Installing ipython2 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-5.1.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for ipython
error: six 1.4.1 is installed but six>=1.9.0 is required by set(['prompt-toolkit'])
```

What can i do to resolve it?

**EDIT:** I tried  `sudo pip install --upgrade six`, but a permission error occurred.

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-GgNJ79-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: As the stack trace says, you need "six>=1.9.0"

Comment: try pip install six==1.9.0 before installing ipython.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that `sudo easy_install ipython` is used to install `ipython`, this is what worked for me, in order to get the latest version of `six`.

`sudo pip install --ignore-installed six`, which is described more analytically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900008/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-when-installing-scrapy-in-osx-10-11).