# Apple Swift is overriding Openstack swift package

Tags: swift, python-2.7

I have installed OpenStack swift python client (pip install python-swiftclient). However /usr/bin has swift executable (which I can not remove as it is owned by root) and is overriding python swift.

Requirement already satisfied: python-swiftclient in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

Requirement already satisfied: requests>=1.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from python-swiftclient)

Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from python-swiftclient)

Requirement already satisfied: futures>=3.0; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "2.6" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from python-swiftclient)

However, I am unable to find python swift anywhere. Please let me know how to resolve this.

Many Thanks
Chen

Answer (score 1):

For me, Apple Swift is under `/usr/bin/swift` and python-swiftclient is under `/usr/bin/local/swift`. Explicitly invoking it as `/usr/bin/local/swift` works.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this post ["OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted" when installing Scrapy in OSX 10.11 (El Capitan) (System Integrity Protection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900008/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-when-installing-scrapy-in-osx-10-11)
and the response by Mario, following commands did the trick

brew unlink python
brew install python 
sudo pip install python-swiftclient

and the python swiftclient does get installed in cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages which previously it did not.