# Mac: OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-XcfgD6

Tags: python, tensorflow, sip

When I played with tensorflow in Mac OS, I got this error:

```
Installing collected packages: html5lib, bleach, markdown, backports.weakref, numpy, funcsigs, pbr, mock, protobuf, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/nl/69lb138j255bkbzzjdx1hb6h0000gp/T/pip-1Jo9RF-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 11):

Add the argument `--ignore-installed` to the pip command you're running. See [this question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900008/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-when-installing-scrapy-in-osx-10-11).

Comment: @MichaelL. It shouldn't be. Unless you have modified any previously installed modules that are being installed with the pip command.

Answer (score 8):

After some google, I got this was caused by mac OS's SIP machine.

So, I reran pip again with the follow command:

```
pip install tensorflow --user -U
```

I finally successfully installed tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install tensorflow --user -U
```

It makes sure that you install the library for just your user if you don't have the admin privileges.