# Python pip install issue - Traceback errors while installing Twilio

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I tried to use `pip install twilio`, also tried to `$sudo pip install twilio`, kept getting the following error, couldn't find solutions elsewhere, please help:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-XS_kT9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pyOpenSSL-0.13.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900008/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-when-installing-scrapy-in-osx-10-11

Comment: What is your OS ?

Comment: @Zcode Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5

Answer (score 1):

Install python again:

```
brew install python
```

and then try:

```
pip install twilio or sudo pip install twilio
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out.
Apparently, I had Python 3.6 installed on top of the default Python 2.7 come with Mac OS. So every time when I do `pip install twilio`, it's looking into the default 2.7 library when the pip is install in Python3. 
So I was able to resolve it by running :

```
Python3 pip install twilio
```