# Error: No available formula with the name "openstacksdk"

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, openstack

From the [openstacksdk install doc](https://developer.openstack.org/sdks/python/openstacksdk/users/index.html), I use :

```
 sudo pip install openstacksdk
```

I will get the Operation not permitted error:

```
...
Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-Z66XCg-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

And I refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900008/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-when-installing-scrapy-in-osx-10-11):

I use brew to install it, get this error:

```
...
==> Deleted Formulae
go-gui                                     kafka@0.80                                 phantomjs@1.92                             phantomjs@1.98

Error: No available formula with the name "openstacksdk" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

My operation system is macOS Sierra 10.12.6

---

**EDIT-1**

After I use `brew install python`, I re-install the `sudo pip install openstacksdk`, still get the same error.

---

**EDIT-2**

I use the :

```
git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
```

But still get the same upper error.

---

**EDIT-3**

I use the which pip, get the bellow message:

```
which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

Comment: Try running what homebrew suggested: `git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow`

Comment: Read the post you linked. It doesn't say to do `brew install openstacksdk` but to do `brew install python` and then use `pip install openstacksdk` because the default install `pip` has a problem.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein wait I verify it.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein I still get the error.

Comment: What do you get when you do `which pip`?

Comment: @NiekdeKlein See my edit-3