# Cannot install smartsheet-python-sdk

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I want to use the SmartSheet API.  I am trying to install the SmartSheet module for Python from the following page:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smartsheet-python-sdk

I have tried using the command **sudo pip install
   smartsheet-python-sdk** on Terminal.

I have tried using **pip
   install smartsheet-python-sdk**.

I'm not sure which is correct but I get the following error when I try to install it.

I tried manually installing this but wasn't sure how to do it after downloading it from GitHub.

I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6.3 installed on my Mac.

1. Is this a Python version issue?  If so, how do I uninstall Python 3?  I installed it with Homebrew.
2. Is this a problem with six?  I saw documentation about problems with six and tried to install it using pip with an "ignore six" at the end of the pip line.
3. Can I still use SmartSheet without the SmartSheet module for Python?
4. How do you install a module downloaded from GitHub?  Which directory should it go in so it can be found by Terminal?

Requirement already satisfied: smartsheet-python-sdk in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.11.1-py2.7.egg (from smartsheet-python-sdk)
Collecting six>=1.9 (from smartsheet-python-sdk)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from smartsheet-python-sdk)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from smartsheet-python-sdk)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-toolbelt in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from smartsheet-python-sdk)
Installing collected packages: six
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-VF5C02-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'

Comment: it would be more readable if you post a screenshot of the error instead of copying pasting it

Answer (score 0):

The error in your log is at the bottom:

> OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:

This may be a problem with your python installation (New security issues on Sierra) [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900008/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-when-installing-scrapy-in-osx-10-11) suggests reinstalling python as one possible solution.

```
brew install python
```