# Troubleshoot PIP on MacOS

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to run following command:
`pip install boto3`

It looks like is start downloading and then show errors:

```
Collecting boto3
  Downloading boto3-1.6.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (128kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 2.7MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from boto3)
Collecting botocore<1.10.0,>=1.9.11 (from boto3)
  Downloading botocore-1.9.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.1MB 278kB/s
Collecting s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 (from boto3)
  Using cached s3transfer-0.1.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil<2.7.0,>=2.1 (from botocore<1.10.0,>=1.9.11->boto3)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from botocore<1.10.0,>=1.9.11->boto3)
  Using cached docutils-0.14-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10->boto3)
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil<2.7.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.10.0,>=1.9.11->boto3)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, docutils, botocore, s3transfer, boto3
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/12/8qvv2_x53rz6ww3t22j2qbr80000gn/T/pip-E6G8ue-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

This is recently start happening.
How to troubleshoot from here?
Do I need to reinstall something and what is recommended way to use PIP?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900008/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-when-installing-scrapy-in-osx-10-11

Comment: `pip install boto3 --user`. Always install python packages with the `--user` flag.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.. Why is this a case?