# Running python script in Mac OSX launchd permission issue

Tags: python, macos, launchd, macos-catalina

I have a simple python script which is moving files from my download folder. The script works fine when I running it via terminal. The issue happens when it gets run through launchd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ben/Project/Automation/CleanDownload.py", line 11, in <module>
    for f in listdir(downloadFolder):
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/ben/Downloads/'
```

Any Idea why?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the workaround that I used to circumvent this issue. I was trying to run a simple shell script, but the same workaround would apply to a Python script. To summarize, the steps involved are:

- Create an automator application called e.g. run-script.app that has a single bash script which runs whatever file is passed to it
- Either give the full automator application **Full Disk Access** via **Security & Privacy** or run it once manually and click **Allow** when macOS prompts for permissions
- Call the automator application with whatever script you want to run

More details:

- Whatever script you're wanting to run, make sure it's executable (using `chmod +x`) and that you have the right `#!` line at the top of the script (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`). In this example, I'll use a script at `~/scripts/organize-screenshots.sh` that moves screenshots from my desktop to my Google Drive directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
user_dir="/Users/soxley"

find "$user_dir"/Desktop -name 'Screen Shot *.png' -exec mv {} "$user_dir"/Google\ Drive/pictures/screenshots/ \;
```

- Next, create an Automator application:

  - Open **Automator**
  - Click **New Document**
  - Select **Application**
  - Click **Choose**
  - Select **Utilities > Run Shell Script**
  - Select **Pass Input: as arguments**
  - Enter `/bin/bash -c "$1"` as the body of the script (see screenshot below)
  - Click **File > Save** and save the application wherever you'd like (`run-script.app` in this example)
- Next, run the application that was just created manually to make sure it has the permissions it needs (you could also grant **Full Disk Access** to the new application in **Security & Privacy**):

  - Open **Terminal.app**
  - Execute the command `open -a run-script.app organize-screenshots.sh`
  - Click **Allow** when macOS asks if the application can access your Desktop
- Now you're ready to configure your script in launchd. Update your .plist with the following `ProgramArguments`:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>open</string>
  <string>-a</string>
  <string>/Users/soxley/scripts/run-script.app</string>
  <string>/Users/soxley/scripts/organize-screenshots.sh</string>
</array>
```

Now you should be able to run whatever script you want using this application as a wrapper.
[image: Automator Application Selection]
[image: Automator Application Content]

Comment: I had to add <string>--args</string> to be able to pass the script name to the run-script.app.

Comment: Automator script works & has full access, but launchd still does not. Could you provide the rest of the setup or a link to it? (There are too many different instructions) -- edit: It does work! My error was not using the user Library path `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` but `/Library/LaunchAgents/`. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying this wrapper-app approach, but to obtain Camera permission, rather than Full Disk Access. I can create the app, run it from a terminal to get the permission prompt, and everything works fine. However, when I run it via my LaunchDaemon, I get "kLSNoLaunchPermissionErr: User doesn't have permission to launch the app (managed networks)". Is there a step that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

if you havent seen this check out ["OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted" when installing Scrapy in OSX 10.11 (El Capitan) (System Integrity Protection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900008/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-when-installing-scrapy-in-osx-10-11)

and this
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339862/ls-operation-not-permitted-mojave-security

according to **Roger**
go to 
Go to **System Preferences** -> **Security & Privacy**

and give Full Disk Access to `Terminal`.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8637915

Comment: thanks for the answer as mentioned, it works fine from the terminal. The issue shows up when I'm running it from launchd.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving `/sbin/launchd` Full Disk Access?

Answer (score 0):

I was breaking my head on this issue for Big Sur for a LONG Time. What worked for me was the following :

1. Grant Full Disk Access to Python3
2. Grant Full Disk Access to launchd & launchctl