# How to execute a shell script from my python script in Mac OS X Catalina 10.15 without Operation not permitted (126) error message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, macos, shell

**ENVIRONMENT:**

Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7

**Python 3.10**

PROBLEM:

I am trying to execute a shell script from my python script in Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.

Here is my code:

```
shell_script_install_Project = 'Project_Install.sh'
print(f"shell_script_install_Project:{shell_script_install_Project}")
command_install_Project = f"""/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "/bin/bash {shell_script_install_Project} >> {os.environ['HOME']}/Project/log.log" with prompt "Project need to install some programs." with administrator privileges'"""
proc = subprocess.Popen(command_install_Project, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = proc.communicate()
print(output.decode("utf8"))
print(err.decode("utf8"))
returncode_command_install_Project = proc.wait()
print(f"returncode_command_install_Project : {returncode_command_install_Project}")
```

And here is the output:

```
shell_script_install_Project:Project_Install.sh    
0:164: execution error: /bin/bash: Project_Install.sh: Operation not permitted (126)

0:164: execution error: /bin/bash: Project_Install.sh: Operation not permitted (126)

returncode_command_install_Project : 1
returncode_command_install_Project : 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried to run the script with sudo:

```
sudo python3 test2.py
```

But I get same issue:

```
shell_script_install_Project:Project_Install.sh

0:164: execution error: /bin/bash: Project_Install.sh: Operation not permitted (126)

returncode_command_install_Project : 1
```

How to execute a shell script from my python script in Mac OS X Catalina 10.15 without Operation not permitted (126) error message?

**UPDATE:**

I follow the instruction suggested in comment : "Change privilege of "bash" program in Security & Privacy. But I faced another problem:

I tried to do it by hand. I have a problem. I don't see the /bin/bash. And when I want to add it, I don't have access to the "bin" repertory.

[image]

So I did it for sh and I edit my code to execute my script with /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash

And I get same result:

```
shell_script_install_Projectt:Project_Install.sh

0:162: execution error: /bin/sh: Project_Install.sh: Operation not permitted (126)
```

I found how to add the bash in the "Full disk access" :
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376474/enabling-bin-bash-on-catalina-invisible-to-system-preferences-security-p

I restart my MAC and restart the terminal. But I still get the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with permissions on Catalina, not a specific Python issue. You have to the grant *[full disk access]* to `/bin/bash`

[image]

More info on [apple.stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376474/enabling-bin-bash-on-catalina-invisible-to-system-preferences-security-p)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do that with a python line of code?

Comment: @GauthierButtez [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234661/running-python-script-in-mac-osx-launchd-permission-issue) helps? BTW I think the best solution would be to change manually the first time the permissions

Comment: I tried to do it by hand. I have a problem. I don't see the /bin/bash. And when I want to add it, I don't have access to the "bin" repertory.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and update my question

Comment: ok. I get it here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376474/enabling-bin-bash-on-catalina-invisible-to-system-preferences-security-p

Comment: Your solution didn't work :-(